# Kendo Grid add new record event,how to catch it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In kendo grid add new record has a event as following:

```
 if (e.model.isNew())
```

but for this I have to write it inside "edit:",is there any other function or way I can use it outside of grid scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always *bind* the [`edit`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) event after the initialization and handle the *create* there. Note that the documentation says the `edit` event handles both *create* and *edit*, so there is no `create` event in the widget, only `edit`:

```
function grid_edit(e) {
  if (!e.model.isNew()) {
    // Disable the editor of the "id" column when editing data items
    var numeric = e.container.find("input[name=id]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    numeric.enable(false);
  }
}

$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("edit", grid_edit);
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aFIMe)